# Solidity - push value in mapping of mapping

Tags: solidity, ether

How can I process to push value in this mapping ?

```
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) public wallet;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push value into mapping, this only works with arrays. You can, however assign values to mapping at a specific index. For ex:

```
wallet[id][msg.sender]  = value;//where value is an uint
```

If you have an array inside the mapping, then you can push values into that array like this:

```
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address=>uint256[])) public wallet;
wallet[id][msg.sender].push(value);// here you can push value into the array because you're assigning an array of values to a specific address for a specific id.
```

It depends a lot of what you're trying to achieve, but this should be a start.